# SQL query - restriction doesn't work as I 'd expect

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
(substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(qot_sup_xpressfeed, ',[^,]+,'), 2, length(REGEXP_SUBSTR(qot_sup_xpressfeed, ',[^,]+,')) - 2)) ,
xex.xex_xexc_k,
  FROM qot, sec, exc, ctr, xcx, xex, xexc, xcrr, crr
 WHERE qot_source = 'X'
       AND qot_id = 2029557521
       AND nvl(qot_real_exc_id, qot_exc_id) = exc_id
       AND exc_ctr_id = ctr_id
       AND qot_sec_id = sec_id
       AND nvl(qot_real_exc_id, qot_exc_id) = xex_exc_id(+)
       AND qot_crr_id = xcx_crr_id(+)
       AND xex_xexc_k = xexc_k(+)
       AND xcx_xcrr_k = xcrr_k(+)
       AND qot_crr_id = crr_id(+)
       AND qot_status IN (1, 2)
      AND (qot_sup_xpressfeed IS NULL OR to_number(substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(qot_sup_xpressfeed, ',[^,]+,'), 2, length(REGEXP_SUBSTR(qot_sup_xpressfeed, ',[^,]+,')) - 2)) = xexc_k);
```

When I comment out the last restriction`AND (qot_sup_xpressfeed IS NULL OR to_number(substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(qot_sup_xpressfeed, ',[^,]+,'), 2, length(REGEXP_SUBSTR(qot_sup_xpressfeed, ',[^,]+,')) - 2)) = xexc_k);` I'm getting results:

```
1135    67
1135    111
1135    549
1135    246
1135    103
1135    564
1135    1135
1135    21
```

So as you can see I have a row:

1135    1135

But I'm getting no results  when I add the last  restriction:

```
 AND (qot_sup_xpressfeed IS NULL OR to_number(substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(qot_sup_xpressfeed, ',[^,]+,'), 2, length(REGEXP_SUBSTR(qot_sup_xpressfeed, ',[^,]+,')) - 2)) = xexc_k);
```

I'd expect I will get 1 result (the mentioned `1135 1135`).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting `xex.xex_xexc_k` while your test is on `xexc_k`. As this is an OUTER JOIN they could be different. What happens when you compare with `xex.xex_xexc_k` instead?